# Rails helper methods for certain REST actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

When I do a rake routes, I see that helper methods are available for certain REST actions for my user model such as new_user, edit_user so I can use methods like new_user_path, edit_user_path etc but they are not available for update or destroy action. To invoke the destroy action, I have to do something like this

```
link_to ‘Destroy’, user_path, :method => :delete
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because there is no need. A combination of http verb and URI should be sufficient to determine whether it is an update or destroy action. 
here is a list of http verb and URI combination from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), from which you can see 'update' and 'destroy' share the same URI as 'show', the only difference is http verb.

**GET   /photos**   Photos  index
display a list of all photos

**GET   /photos/new**   Photos  new
return an HTML form for creating a new photo

**POST  /photos**   Photos  create
create a new photo

**GET   /photos/1**     Photos  show
display a specific photo

**GET   /photos/1/edit**    Photos  edit
return an HTML form for editing a photo

**PUT   /photos/1**     Photos  update
update a specific photo

**DELETE    /photos/1**     Photos  destroy
delete a specific photo

Comment: While 'update' and 'destroy' share the same URI as 'show', for consistency sake, I would argue that it is better to having matching update and destroy helper methods, it's what I was looking for initially and couldn't get working until I saw a post on the different style of method call for 'update' and 'destroy'.